# Assigning value to a variable inside an If else block in swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8

This thing is so basic I am sure its been asked but I can't find it.

I am experimenting in swift 3 playgrounds and I want to run this code:

```
import UIKit

var optionalVariable: Int? = 32
var anotherVariable: Int
if optionalVariable != nil{
    print("This executed")
    anotherVariable = 32
}
print(anotherVariable)
```

It fails to run and I am getting this error:

```
Playground execution failed: error: chapter4.playground:5:7:
error: variable 'anotherVariable' used before being initialized
print(anotherVariable)
```

So what's wrong? Why can't I use the value of `anotherVariable` when I have assigned a value to it?

If I comment out the last line `print(anotherVariable)`,
the code runs and the output is printed as `This executed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler see that there is a path where the `anotherVariable` is not initialized (when `optionalVariable` is `nil`). This could happen if e.g. another thread sets this optional variable to `nil`. It won't happen in your code but the compiler can't know this. You have to initialize the `anotherVariable` at some point before you pass it to a function.

Comment: I did not understand. When I comment out the last line where I am using the value of `anotherVariable` the code runs. So the value of 32 should be assigned to `anotherVariable`. So why is it saying its not initialised?

Comment: I got it. I set `anotherVariable` to `0` before the If statement and now my code runs. Thanks . But coming from C (i can't say I know much of C), I find it strange that this happens.

Comment: In Swift variables are just not initialized with any value if they are not optionals. Optionals default to `nil` but non-optionals can't do this because 0 is a value like any other.

Answer (score 2):

There's an iron rule in Swift: **Any variable must be initialized before using its value.**

---

The line

```
var anotherVariable: Int
```

**declares** the variable but doesn't **initialize** it.

If `optionalVariable` is nil, `anotherVariable` doesn't get initialized and will cause a crash. The compiler can detect that at compile time and displays an error message.

---

Either assign a default value, change the declaration line to

```
var anotherVariable = 10 // or 0 or whatever
```

or add an `else` clause

```
var optionalVariable: Int? = 32
var anotherVariable: Int
if optionalVariable != nil{
    print("This executed")
    anotherVariable = 32
} else {
    anotherVariable = 10
}
print(anotherVariable)
```

Comment: Or, a 3rd option, make the variable an `Int?`

Comment: @ConnorNeville According to Swift's strong type system you should avoid optionals as much as possible.

Comment: @vadian no, optionals are not bad at all. they can add more semantics to your variables, when some kind of variable can be something or nothing, not magic values like `0` or `-1`. Plus they add more type safety because they don't make app to crash when they are `nil`.

Comment: the else clause is slightly better option than having to artificially set a value beforehand

Comment: @Crazyrems Optionals aren't bad, but *add more type safety* regarding optionals is often mistaken for don't-care. And non-optionals will never crash the app because they cannot be `nil`.

Comment: @vadian Sometimes it's good to have `nil`, but when they can be non-optional it's better you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable is declared an an Int

```
var anotherVariable: Int
```

The problem is that when you print the variable it can be uninitialized (when `optionalVariable` is `nil`). An `Int` must have a value and the compiler doesn't set a default value for you unless it's an optional type. Any type or class should have a value before it's first use, that's the reason you had no error when you commented your `print` line.

There's two choices to fix that.

- Make sure that `anotherVariable` is initialized at some point, by initializing at declaration

  ```
  var anotherVariable: Int = 0
  ```

  or by doing so in an `else` case

  ```
  if optionalVariable != nil{
      print("This executed")
      anotherVariable = 32
  }
  else {
      anotherVariable = 0
  }
  ```
- or make `anotherVariable` optional (declare it as a `Int?`)

  ```
  var anotherVariable: Int?
  ```

  That way it's `nil` by default. That's the same as

  ```
  var anotherVariable: Int? = nil
  ```

---

If you come from C, it's to prevent some edge cases where variable contains values from previous allocations.